# Do i have to pay any fees to Salesforce before putting my paid app in AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange

i have developed an hybrid app which is having some apex code in salesforce which makes callout to the .net webservice which is also built by me only. i want to list my app in AppExchange listing as a paid app once i passed the Salesforce review.

I know that there are some security review reports which we need to submit to salesforce before going for the review. And i understand we need to get Burp License and run my .net app and get pass certificate. **Now, when i try to register for Burp License it reports me an error that i need to fulfill the prerequisites before i requested for a Burp License. **How much fees i need to pay salesforce in order to list my app in AppExchange?**** it has been a pricking question for me and am expecting correct guidelines from any of the experts here in this board?

Answer (score 18):

### Security Review Fees (aka Listing Fees):

As of September 1 2013, **the security review for new paid apps is $2,700 USD per app**, up from the previous cost of $300 USD.

The annual review fee (aka "AppExchange listing fee") for paid apps remains $150 USD per app.

This change will not impact partners with free AppExchange apps (which I believe currently get free security review and free annual review).

Here's the blog post from Salesforce announcing the price increase:

**http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/08/salesforce-appexchange.html**

### AppExchange Partner models:

You may also be interested in looking at AppExchange Partner models (aka "ISVForce" and "Force.com Embedded").

http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/

The more common of these two is **ISVForce**.  ISVForce is used to sell apps to people who are already Salesforce customers.  Force.com Embedded is used to sell your app to people who are **NOT** Salesforce customers - these people get a version of Salesforce along with your app.

As of September 2013, paid apps in ISVForce pay 15% revenue to Salesforce. In return the primary benefits that you get are:

1. Two (2) Enterprise Licenses for Salesforce to use for your company
2. Use of the Salesforce License Management App (LMA). The LMA gives you a way to manage licensing of your app for your customers
3. The opportunity to participate in paid advertising on the AppExchange

In addition two these two partner models, you can choose to use **AppExchange Checkout**.

If you choose to be an AppExchange Checkout partner, you will still pay a 15% revenue share plus a small per transaction fee. You will get the first two benefits above (2 licenses and use of the LMA). You will also get the ability to use AppExchange Checkout to automatically charge your customers credit cards for payment. This is a great option for low cost apps that are simple for customers to set-up on their own.

Here's some more info on AppExchange Checkout:

**https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout**

Answer (score 7):

Free apps are free to list, but for paid apps (from memory) you have to pay $2700 for the security review. Once you've paid to submit an app for security review you should be provided with a free Bupr licence to test your app. Additionally you have to pay $150 per year to keep the app listed.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 16, 2023:

- The $2,550 initial review fee is eliminated.
- The $150 annual fee is eliminated.
- The security review fee is $999 per attempt for paid apps.
- There will be no fees for Security Reviews for free solutions while Salesforce works to redefine the policy.

Source: https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/pcnews/appexchange-security-review-fee-updates-MC4W7STFOTRNCO5C52G27DQK5J7Y?language=en_US