# AppExchange Partner Program Models

Tags: appexchange

What are the AppExchange Partner Program Models ? What is 15% and 25% net revenue in the models ?
I got this values stated on http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/ this link.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create an ISV app (to publish on the appexchange) and you want to sell and use it as a standalone app, meaning when someone logs in your app the only thing they can see, do and use, are the objects, tabs, logic, and everything else you created yourself to be in your app (for example a software suite to manage a car-park)

This way you can market and sell your app to anyone interested (your customers don't need to already have a Salesforce license)
This means that besides the revenue you get for your app, salesforce doesn't get anything else (no license fees), meaning you'll have to give salesforce **25%** of your revenue, for use of the platform.

When however you create an app that works more like a plug-in to existing salesforce logic (for example an invoicing module that works based on the data in Opportunities). Your client already has a salesforce license, and salesforce gets revenue from those licenses already, and salesforce is so kind to lower the cost for the use of the platform down to **15%** of the revenue you generate only with your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the difference at a high level.

**ISVforce** (15% revenue share) is to sell your app to customers who already use Salesforce.  This is the more common model for apps listed on the AppExchange.

**Force.com Embedded** (25% revenue share) (also called OEM) is to sell your app to customers who don't use Salesforce.

With Force.com Embedded, you as the app developer, develop your app using Salesforce's technologies (aka the "Force.com Platform").  Then you sell the thing to your customer, and pay 25% to Salesforce for using their technologies.  These technologies include the cloud database, hosting, login, security, licensing, and so on.

See this response for more info on **the costs of ISVForce vs. Force.com Embedded:**

**[Do i have to pay any fees to Salesforce before putting my paid app in AppExchange?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7766/do-i-have-to-pay-any-fees-to-salesforce-before-putting-my-paid-app-in-appexchang/16659#16659)**