# Salesforce AppExchange app publishing

Tags: appexchange, lightning-apps, app, product

There were few doubts related to AppExchange that I wanted to clarify

1. Can I create AppExchange package without being a PArtner?
2. If I need to be a partner, do I need to pay something or own a company?
3. Is there any possibility of publishing paid apps without being partner? Or publish a free app without paying anything

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes you can create package without being a partner because only developer account is required to create a package but if you want to publish that on app exchange you need a partner account.
2. No, Partner exchange program is completely free for any user.
3. You can't publish app without being partner. Free apps are free to list, but for paid apps you have to pay $2700 for the security review + 15% revenue share.

See this response for more info on the costs of ISVForce vs. Force.com Embedded:

[Do i have to pay any fees to Salesforce before putting my paid app in AppExchange?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7766/do-i-have-to-pay-any-fees-to-salesforce-before-putting-my-paid-app-in-appexchang/16659#16659)

[Salesforce ISV partner Help](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Signup)

Comment: But to be registered as an AppExchange partner, I need to have my own company and website and stuff? As it is asking for website and company name while registration. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes you need to have a company with website.

Comment: @KaushikRay. You can also be a "sole proprietor". You don't need to be a "business entity" as in an LLC or Corporation. For a web site, you can always use an "AboutMe" page if you need to while getting started. Once you release your app, you'll definitely want a web site to support it, but you can do that through your ISV partner Org that you'll have available to you for free. All this can be answered easily in the Partner Community.

Comment: @crmprogdev just curious can we write sole proprietor in Company name field or N/A?

Comment: Just write your own name in if you're the sole proprietor. You can also put in pretty much any name you want to use that doesn't infringe on someone else's as a "DBA" (Doing Business As) provided you're going to register it according to the laws that apply to you. Where I'm located, it would be with the county in TX I either reside in or do business in or both.

Comment: @crmprogdev , That is really very helpful man..!!! I do have a website, but do not have a corporation or entity. So that sounds great. Thanks